# facebook login integration isnt getting my userID

Tags: php, facebook, fbconnect

I follow this tutorial to integrated facebook : http://25labs.com/tutorial-integrate-facebook-connect-to-your-website-using-php-sdk-v-3-x-x-which-uses-graph-api/

The problem is that when i click the login link and allow the app,when i print_r the $_SESSION i get

```
Array ( [fb_**MY_APP_ID**_state] => 22decb94e83299b9c31113623621eeb2 [userID] => )
```

Why it didnt get my user id ?!

You can see the hole script here:

[I cant make the Facebook PHP-SDK 3.x register/login user integration to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262857/i-cant-make-the-facebook-php-sdk-3-x-register-login-user-integration-to-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just try http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

it's an up to date & working tutorial with latest php sdk

Comment: you can also look at the official documentation given on this page by facebook https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Comment: I copy all from the tutorial and again no luck ... also is annoying that to the redirection url is add a ?state=VeryLongHash... When i print the $_SESSION i get only the state session and the userID is empty